# Query by city name on geolite2 .mmdb file (JAVA)

Tags: java, geoip, geoip2, geolite2

I am using GeoLite2 to get Location by IP address for my java appliccation.

I want to get country by city from GeoLite2-City.mmdb file.

This is my reader :

```
DatabaseReader reader = new DatabaseReader.Builder(dbFileStream).withCache(new CHMCache()).build();
```

I am getting CityResponse by IP address like below :

```
 CityResponse cityResponse = reader.city(InetAddress.getByName("an IP address"));
```

But I want to get Country name by city like this :

```
String countryName = reader.getCountryByCity("Paris”);
```

Is there any way to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible. The database is designed to do lookups by IP address. I would suggest using the CSV files that MaxMind provides if you need to access the data in some other way.

Also, you can try project [geonames.org](http://www.geonames.org/) and [their java-api library](http://www.geonames.org/source-code/)