# query maxmind mmdb for country when given a city

Tags: maxmind

I'm looking to get a city to country mapping without an IP address
I have access to these files on my box:

```
GeoIP2Country.mmdb  
GeoIPCountry.dat 
GeoIP2City.mmdb        
GeoIPCity.dat   
GeoIP2ISP.mmdb      
GeoIP2Connections.mmdb
```

Normally the way I would use this is `GeoIP2Country.country(cip).country.name` and it would return a country name for the IP I feed it.

In my use case I want to provide it with a city name and have it return a country name. Since all the data is in there this would save me a lot of time. Is it possible to query mmdb (no idea how to do this) then convert that to a dataframe so I can just have a df of country to city mapping or vise versa?

Answer (score 0):

based on this :[Query by city name on geolite2 .mmdb file (JAVA)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51740363/query-by-city-name-on-geolite2-mmdb-file-java) I cant do what I wnated to.

BUT there is also a country_code.csv I think thats offered by maxmind which does what I need in conjunction with some other non mmdb files.